# Truffle-contract error on deployed contract

Tags: web3js, truffle, javascript

Playing around with the gnosis multisig, using truffle-contract to interact with already deployed MultiSigWallet using truffle migrate.

Contents of the file I am trying to run:

```
var contract = require('truffle-contract');

var fs = require('fs');
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:9545');
var provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:9545');

var fileData = fs.readFileSync('./build/contracts/MultiSigWallet.json');
var jsonData = JSON.parse(fileData.toString());

var myContract = contract(jsonData);
myContract.setProvider(provider);

myContract.deployed().then(function(instance) {
        var deployed = instance;
        return deployed.address;
})
.then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
})
.catch(err => { 
        console.log(err);  
});
```

When I run using node, get error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at Provider.sendAsync (/home/delphi/MultiSigWallet/node_modules/truffle-contract/contract.js:24:36)
    at RequestManager.sendAsync (/home/delphi/MultiSigWallet/node_modules/truffle-contract/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:80:19)
    at Object.get [as getNetwork] (/home/delphi/MultiSigWallet/node_modules/truffle-contract/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/property.js:116:33)
    at /home/delphi/MultiSigWallet/node_modules/truffle-contract/contract.js:512:27
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Function.detectNetwork (/home/delphi/MultiSigWallet/node_modules/truffle-contract/contract.js:503:14)
    at Function.deployed (/home/delphi/MultiSigWallet/node_modules/truffle-contract/contract.js:451:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/delphi/MultiSigWallet/test.js:14:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
```

The undefined referred to in the error is for myContract.deployed().  I cannot figure out why this is though. Simple console output shows that myContract is not undefined.  Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong?

Comment: Does any of the solutions proposed [here](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract/issues/57)(truffle GitHub repo) help you?

Comment: Changing it to `contract.setProvider(provider.currentProvider)` results in error that provider is undefined, but I checked it's value and it's not undefined?

Answer (score 0):

```
import contract from 'truffle-contract'
```

but, node this file will report error 'SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier'